# Passar o valor do input para outra pagina

Tags: php

Tenho uma pagina onde recebo numa tabela valores da base de dados.

```
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<th>Empresa</th>";
        echo "<th>Categoria</th>";
        echo "<th>Serviço</th>";
        echo "<th>Descrição</th>";
        echo "<th>Pagamento</th>";
        echo "<th>Distrito</th>";
        echo "<th>Investimento</th>";



        echo "</tr>";

    $numLinhas = 0;
    while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {
        $numLinhas++;

        echo "<tr class='table-hover'>";
        //echo "<td>".$produto['id']."-".$numLinhas."º</td>";
        echo "<td>autor:".$produto['user_of'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['categ'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['titulo'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['descricao'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['valor'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['local'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['investimento'] . "</td>";



        echo "<td><input style='width:40px' type='number' name='novo_investimento' value='0'><a href=up_invest.php?id=".$produto['id'].">
        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Ok'></a></td> ";




        echo "</tr>";

    }
        echo "</table>";
```

Nesta mesma tabela tenho um input number ao qual eu chamo 'novo_investimento'.

```
 echo "<td><input style='width:40px' type='number' name='novo_investimento'  value='0'><a href=up_invest.php?id=".$produto['id'].">
        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Ok'></a></td> ";
```

Na pagina up_invest.php, onde os dados são tratados, eu gostaria de pegar o id da linha e o novo valor definido pelo o utilizador do campo 'novo_investimento' dessa linha.

Da maneira que está, na página up_invest.php quando eu faço isto

```
 $id= $_REQUEST['id'];
 $investimento=$_REQUEST['novo_investimento'];
 echo "$id $investimento";
```

ele só pega o id. 
Como faço para pegar o valor do campo 'novo_investimento'?

```
Notice: Undefined index: novo_investimento
```

Com o elemento < form >

```
    echo "<td><form action='up_invest.php' method='post'><input  style='width:40px' type='number' name='novo_investimento' value='0'>
        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Ok'></form></td> ";
```

ele  pega o valor do 'novo_investimento', mas perde o id da linha. Como pego o id da linha onde este form é apresentado?

Resolvido. Criei um campo hidden com o valor ID da linha.

```
 echo "<td><form id='form1' name='form1' action='up_invest.php'  method='post'><input style='width:40px' type='number' name='novo_investimento'  value='0'>

        <input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$produto['id'].">

        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Ok'></form></td> ";
```

Comment: Parece-me correto. Podes colocar o HTML que chega à pagina para ser mais claro como fica o HTML?

Comment: Na página onde trato os dados, não tenho html para já, só queria pegar os valores. Na pagina onde os dados são apresentados a primeira vez é so mesmo uma tabela, onde aparecem nas suas proprias <td>. Eu não estou a conseguir pegar o valor 'novo_investimento'. Não sei porque...

Comment: Coloca esse HTML, mesmo que simples, na pergunta ou num jsFiddle para ver se encontramos o problema... Por exemplo nesse PHP não vejo o elemento `<form>`

Comment: Eu estava com um problema semelhante eu trazia do banco dados por um submit_1 pra uma tabela e caso ela tivesse 50% preenchida precisaria pegar o id e fazer outro submit_2 na mesma pagina ai eu acabei guardando o id do primeiro submit em um input hidden e quando ia preencher o restante da tabela usava esse input hidden pra atualizar com o submit_2. Resumo quando trazer os dados do banco guarde o que vc quer em inputs hidden(ja dentro do form_2) pra usar posteriormente com o submit_2.

Comment: Foi o que acabei por fazer. Criei um hidden input com o valor da linha do ID e passei ela :)

Comment: vou colocar como resposta pra ajudar os demais blz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando enviamos um formulário para o PHP (para o servidor em geral) o que é passado são elementos como input, textarea, select. O PHP recebe uma array associativa onde as chaves sãos os valores do atributo `name` e os valor que é atribuido a cada chave vem do atributo `value`.

Assim se não houver no HTML nenhum elemento deste tipo com `name="id"` então o PHP não vai receber nada. Temos de juntar então algo como

```
<input name='id' value="algumValor" />
```

Se o que queres é guardar o valor dessa linha/id que vem do PHP, e não queres que ele esteja visível,  então podes usar `type="hidden"` e atribuir o `$produto['id']` ao `value` do `input`. Algo assim:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$produto['id']." />";
```

Desse modo o elemento fica invisível mas o servidor recebe na mesma essa informação no `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com um problema semelhante eu trazia do banco, dados por um submit_1 pra uma tabela e caso ela tivesse 50% preenchida precisaria pegar o id e fazer outro submit_2 na mesma pagina. Ai eu acabei guardando o id do primeiro submit_1 em um input hidden e quando ia preencher o restante da tabela usava esse input hidden pra atualizar(update) com o submit_2.

Resumo quando trazer os dados do banco guarde o que vc quer em inputs hidden(já dentro do form_2) pra usar posteriormente com o submit_2